Can you recommend any apps or websites for hearing audio recordings of Scripture in Hebrew or Greek?
I trust this question is ok to ask here, considering I'm enquiring for the purpose of Biblical hermeneutics.
I figure that if there are good apps or websites out there for hearing the Bible read in the original languages, then users here would know.
Ideally I'd like to be able to select individual verses and hear a reading. It would even better, again, if I could select individual words within verses!
I'd be happy if there are free-to-use apps or websites, but if there are good options with paid subscriptions I would certainly consider those.
Thanks in advance.

This Question really belongs on the BH Meta site, but is too old to migrate, and given the lack of substantive answers I'm going to Close it.

Blueletterbible.org is a great beginning...taking a class to understand the language is and has been fascinating! Boker Tov!

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Thanks @Merrymary. I do use Blueletterbible.org very regularly. It's been very useful for hearing the pronunciations of Strongs entries i.e. root words. But I'm currently looking for more than that; I'm looking for resources for hearing full verses read aloud.
Like you, though, I'd certainly like to start taking classes on learning the languages, proper.

is it  something like LibraVox?recordings that you would like to listen to?https://librivox.org

There is a difficulty in how do we know we are in the original language, absent the original speakers.
You may get most of the benefit by reading aloud to yourself. Or if you're regularly reading+speaking with others, such as within a religious or academic institution, then there's a dialect-from-usage.
What I'd suggest is to go on Youtube for an original language reader who fits to what you're doing. There isn't sonic fidelity, there can be quackery around that - but there are ancient traditions who never stopped reading the texts in the original language.
It's unlikely anyone holds back the forces of phonetic drift, or voiceboxes evolving - but that's the life of language. To seek an original language involves preferring what it was over its living self.
